# Delete temporary data when user cancels the transaction

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, php-5.4

I have a form on a website that users fill in to subscribe for a service and then a Paypal button for the users to pay for that service. Before sending the users to Paypal's website, I save the info that the user has submitted in temporary table in my database. My question is this:

How would I know what temporary data to delete if the user cancels the transaction by clicking on the Cancel button on Paypal? I have no information about what the user has submitted once I'm on Paypal website.

Thank you

Comment: Since you tagged IPN i'm assuming you've read about it a little. Use IPN or one of the check out API's to change the status of the transaction after payment is complete.

Answer (score -1):

you'll probably want to setup an IPN so you get pinged on a cancellation; in-turn know what to delete in the db.

[Here is a link on setting  it up](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/)

[Information on it](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/)

[Sample Code](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples)

1. A Simple road is to use the PayPal notification of cancellation via
   email for reference of what was cancelled.
2. Run a download history report and view the '**type**'column where you'll see subscriptions

Comment: I already have IPN set up, the IPN url is called only after the transaction has completed. My question is about BEFORE any transaction to know what to delete when the user cancels.